# Install libapache2-mod-fastcgi on Cubietruck (Debian 7.8)

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, cubieboard

I'm new in the Linux world, but I wanted to install Seafile 4.0.1 on my Cubietruck (Cubieboard 3) with Apache2 and MySQL using these two tutorials:

- http://manual.seafile.com/deploy/deploy_with_apache.html
- http://server-labs.blogspot.ch/2014/05/how-to-install-seafile-with-mysql.html

I ran into a problem as I wanted to install `libapache2-mod-fastcgi`, but the package was not found. I added the *non-free* repos in the *sources.list* file. Didn't help.

Instead I installed `libapache2-mod-fcgi` and continued with the tutorial. At the point when I had to restart the apache2 server, the error `Invalid command 'FastCgiExternalServer` occured.

Any help to solve this problem, did I anything wrong?

Some more information:

It's running on Debian 7.8 and `uname -a` gives output below:

`Linux cubietruck 3.4.79 #3 SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 12 11:39:10 CST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: It sounds like there may be something wrong with your Apache configs.  Can you post the output of `apachectl -t`?

Comment: Syntax error on line 270 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'FastCgiExternalServer', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action '-t' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

I put this line at the very end. Does it matter?

Comment: Yep, looks like a screwed up apache config. Look at the `mod_fcgi` docs and tweak your apache configs until `apachectl -t` reports `Syntax OK`. If you post your Apache configuration, I'm sure somebody can take a look at it and help figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same problem trying to setup seafile with HTTPS on my new Cubietruck (Cubieboard 3).

The problem is that there's no pre-compiled binary for arch 'armhf' in the repos. So it must be compiled.

And I solved it like this:

```
apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev cdbs debhelper dpatch libapr1-dev libtool pkg-config
apt-get -b source libapache-mod-fastcgi
dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi*.deb
# Enable the module if not already done
a2enmod fastcgi
```

You'll get tons of warnings but finally it worked. Now I'm able to use seafile with HTTPS using apache as reverse proxy for seahub.

## My Setup

I'm using the Image from Igor Pecovnik with Kernel 3.4.105 from: 
http://www.igorpecovnik.com/2013/12/24/cubietruck-debian-wheezy-sd-card-image/

```
root@x:~# unname -a
Linux x 3.4.105-cubieboard #8 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 23 06:11:42 EST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

## The error (for searching puposes)

The error you get if you try to apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi:

```
root@x:~# apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-fastcgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate
```